# Java look up closest previous Date in HashMap

Tags: java, date, search, hashmap

I've got a problem to solve, where I need to create an accounting and bookkeeping solutions part in Java (just the backend, for now). They require the system to store previous prices of given products, so I decided to go with a `HashMap<Date,Integer>`.

Now problem is, the system has to be able to retrieve prices in given times, for accounting, tracing back purchases (the order stores the item, and the purchase time, so it can be looked back easily). It would be all good, but if the purchase date does not match the price setting date, the simple get method returns null. And so far I haven't been able to logic out a search method what looks for the first previous date before the purchase date, to return the price.

Is there any suggested way to solve this?

Comment: What are the key/value types in your hashmap?

Comment: Hmm, the system removed it for some reason, but it was Date and Integer.

Comment: it didn't remove them - they were hidden as html. when entering angle brackets, wrap the term in backticks (edit you post to see how I did this for you). also, there was no reason to put an apostrophe in the word "solutions" (I removed that too)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend you to check [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

To get the closest date prior to the `date` you would look it up like this:

```
return map.get(map.headMap(date, true).lastKey());
```

A break down of the above:

- `previous = map.headMap(date, true)` returns all the previous entries (including date)
- `closestMatchingKey = previous.lastKey()` returns the last key in that (above) map
- `map.get(closestMatchingKey)` returns that match (or `null` if none)

---

### Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    TreeMap<Date, String> map = new TreeMap<>();

    map.put(new Date(0), "First");
    map.put(new Date(10), "Second");
    map.put(new Date(20), "Third");
    map.put(new Date(30), "Fourth");
    map.put(new Date(40), "Fifth");

    System.out.println(getClosestPrevious(map, new Date(5)));
    System.out.println(getClosestPrevious(map, new Date(10)));
    System.out.println(getClosestPrevious(map, new Date(55)));
}

private static String getClosestPrevious(TreeMap<Date, String> map, Date date) {
    return map.get(map.headMap(date, true).lastKey());
}
```

**Outputs:**

```
First
Second
Fifth
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the best solution so far, and also the easiest to implement too!

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to use a `TreeMap` and specifically the method [NavigableMap#foorEntry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#floorEntry%28K%29) (my emphasis):

> public Map.Entry floorEntry(K key)
>
> Description copied from interface: NavigableMap Returns a key-value
>   mapping associated with the greatest key **less than or equal to the given key**, or null if there is no such key.
>
> Specified by:
>       floorEntry in interface NavigableMap

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand keys of your map are dates. If so I suggest you to move to `TreeMap` instead of `HashMap` and use your custom comparator that implements the logic of "closest" date. the method `compare()` of your comparator will return 0 when date is close enough to given one without requiring the exact matching.

Comment: Yes, TreeMap seems to be a better solution, although please note that I don't have to find the "closest" date, but the "closest previous". But yes, the logic should be almost the same.